# Linear Programming: An optimality condition involving the dual

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> The primal linear program
>
> \begin{align}
> (P): \max \quad &c^Tx \\
> \text{  s.t.} &Ax \le b,\\ &x \ge 0
> \end{align}
>
> has an optimal solution for all $b$ if and only if for its dual holds:
>
> \begin{align}
> (D): \min \quad &b^Ty \\
> \text{  s.t.} &A^Ty \ge c,\\ &y \ge 0
> \end{align}
>
> has at least one feasible point $y$ and there exists a $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lvert\lvert{y}\rvert\rvert_\infty \le C$.

So far I was able to come up with the following:

$\Longrightarrow:$ The fact that there are feasible points for $(D)$ is a direct consequence of the Duality Theorem, but I do not see why there should be such a $C$.

I have no idea for the other direction. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: The existence of $C$ simply says that the dual solution is bounded. Does this sound familiar?

Comment: @Erik M: Sorry, I do not get it. I understand that by the Duality Theorem we know that $(D)$ has a finite optimal solution since $(P)$ has a finite optimal solution, but I do not see how we could argue that each feasible point $y$ of $(D)$ is bounded.